# Possible to reference an ASP.NET Core 2.0 class library dll from an ASP.NET Webforms project in another solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, portable-class-library, class-library

I recently switched all of my class libraries in one of my solutions to be ASP.NET Core 2.0 class libraries when they were net461 libraries previously.

I usually build and then copy and paste the library dlls to a project in another solution and then simply reference them in VS.

This does not seem to be working anymore. Do I have to make these new 2.0 libraries local NuGet packages instead?

Do I need to change the TargetFramework of my .NET Core class libraries to be .NET Standard 2.0?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what the actual problem is;  "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  What is the exact wording of any error messages you are getting?  Can you post some code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am getting errors in the older webforms solution saying: The type DateTime is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.. I am getting these errors wherever the class library is referenced in my code. My question is if it is possible to do a reference like this or does it need to be a .NET standard class library.

Comment: Isn't `DateTime` in the System assembly?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but I think the error is happening because I am reference a .dll that is from a .NET Core Class Library not a .NET Standard Class Library. I am wondering if it is even possible to reference a .NET Core Class Library from a standard .NET Webforms project and if so how because that is why the errors are happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to change the TargetFramework of my .NET Core class libraries to be .NET Standard 2.0?

It depends. If all of your class libraries (including the applications that depend on them) target .NET Core, then no you shouldn't need to.

But if you intend the libraries to be shared between .NET Core and .NET Framework applications (or other [platforms .NET Standard supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)), then you should make them .NET Standard.

Comment: In the libraries that need to be referenced by .NET Framework applications I added multiple references to both: <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks> then I copy and paste the dlls from the netstandard2.0 folder after building. Does this make sense? It works for me since the app code is still netcoreapp2.0 compatible.

Comment: Okay. Technically, there is no need to multi-target. `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` should do the trick. If your goal is to consume the library from `.NET Core 2.0` and `.NET Framework 4.6.1`, you only need to target `.NET Standard 2.0` and it will work in both cases, provided you have those frameworks installed on the target machine.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. So even within my Solution that has all .NET Core projects those specific class libraries can simply target .NET Standard 2.0 and still be referenced by a .NET Core Web API for example right? And then the dlls can also be exported to the .NET Web App in another solution.

Comment: If by `exported to the .NET Web App in another solution` you actually meant `consumed by a .NET Framework application (including ASP.NET) in another solution`, that's correct.